# endPoints of JsPlumb are not updating within container with scroll overflow when dragging them

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, overflow, jsplumb

I have two draggable layers and there is a connection between them which is based on [JsPlumb](http://jsplumb.org/)  library. Working example is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bGcVH/4/). The picture is here:

[image]

When these layers are located in the body there is no any problems, but when I put them inside another layer (i.e. container) with `overflow: auto OR scroll;` the problem starts to show itself. When you move a layer outside the visible area of the container the endpoints of the draggable layers don't move with a draggable layer but instead they (endpoints) stop in the border of the container.

The author of the JsPlumb library had solved this problem for a JsPlumb 1.2.x version [here](http://code.google.com/p/jsplumb/source/browse/trunk/tests/ContainerWithScrollOverflowTest.html?r=621), but UNFORTUNATELY this script doesn't work anymore for JsPlumb 1.3.x. Does anybody know how this problem could be solved? I (and think many developers) really need to solve this problem (if it hadn't been solved yet, because I had googled and didn't find anything useful).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the author of jsPlumb library I was able to solve the problem. He has released a new RC version of the library for the appeared problem and now the problem is gone! Working example is is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bGcVH/9/).